# Roo 1.1.5 super basic application is buggy

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-roo, datanucleus

I'm using Roo 1.1.5, with Eclipse STS, here is what I do: I create a new Spring Roo Project from Eclipse, and in the Roo Shell, I type the following:

```
persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database H2_IN_MEMORY 
entity --class ~.domain.Task
field string --fieldName description --notNull --sizeMin 3 --sizeMax 512
field boolean --fieldName completed --notNull
controller all --package ~.controller
```

A [more verbose description is in my blog](http://www.stefanolocati.it/blog/?p=1115), but what reported above is basically what I do.

In a web browser I can create and list tasks just fine, but if I try to edit (update) a Task, instead a new duplicated task is created... Possible that a bug like this has slipped in? Or is it something I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: to be faster I've run the script from the command line and tried with all persistence providers.

```
$ roo
roo> project --topLevelPackage task --java 6 --projectName Task
roo> persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database H2_IN_MEMORY 
roo> entity --class ~.domain.Task
roo> field string --fieldName description --notNull --sizeMin 3 --sizeMax 512
roo> field boolean --fieldName completed --notNull
roo> controller all --package ~.controller
roo> exit
$ mvn tomcat:run #or mvn jetty:run
```

Here are the results:

## DATANUCLEUS AND DATANUCLEUS_2 WITH H2

Roo + Datanucleus + H2 results in a buggy application, updating results in duplicated records.

## ECLIPSELINK WITH H2

Build failure

> The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.0, org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:jar:2.0.3: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.2.0 in spring-maven-release (http://maven.springframework.org/release)

## OPENJPA WITH H2

Works, with warnings. Example:

> WARN   [main] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'persistenceUnit', root URL [file:/home/stefano/workspace/task4/target/classes/]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.

## HIBERNATE WITH H2

works

## DATANUCLEUS WITH GOOGLE APP ENGINE

Works...

```
project --topLevelPackage task --java 6 --projectName Task
persistence setup --provider DATANUCLEUS --database GOOGLE_APP_ENGINE \
    --applicationId appid
entity --class ~.domain.Task
field string --fieldName description --notNull --sizeMin 3 --sizeMax 512
field boolean --fieldName completed --notNull
controller all --package ~.controller
exit
mvn gae:run
```

Comment: Can't see (on the face of that description) where there is any problem with DataNucleus, since it obviously passes JPA TCK etc like all the others. If you believe otherwise, split it down to the actual model classes and persistence code, then there is basis for *us* to comment (as opposed to Spring, which is what you present right now, and I've no idea what they put in for DataNucleus in those situations ... since they're controlling what is called with what arguments).

Comment: @DataNucleus I don't know if the bug is in DataNucleus (and actually looking the body of the question gives this impression, I've  edited it to clarify). There is a bug in the interaction H2 - DataNucleus - Roo and the bug is somewhere in there. I will break it down and let you know, thanks for the comment.

Comment: Are you perhaps hitting this https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1467   The JPA spec leaves many things open to interpretation. In DataNucleus 3 there is a flag to get various different types of behaviour for merge to cater for all eventualities.

Comment: @DataNucleus looks like it is... will see if it will get fixed in the upcoming roo 1.2 release. If you want, you can post your comment as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps hitting this [JIRA ROO-1467](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1467). The JPA spec leaves many things open to interpretation. In DataNucleus 3 there is a flag to get various different types of behaviour for merge to cater for all eventualities.

Comment: Spring 1.2.0 has been released, it's using DataNucleus 3.0.4, I tried to add `datanucleus.allowAttachOfTransient`, but it's still not working. I've posted a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553495/roo-1-2-0-basic-application-with-datanucleus-still-buggy).

Answer (score 0):

I have tryed your script (but I used Hibernate instead of datanucleus because of some not found dependencies). But it worked for me with out any problem.

So may the problem is datanucleus releated, or it "outside" of this script.

Comment: I've updated my question... I tried all the available providers.